# Regarding enums and classes in c++ and how they work

Tags: c++, class, enums

I am confused about how enums work with classes..

Here is my test code... yes I know it doesn't work...
http://ideone.com/oy3VH

Basically I have the test functions working... Testing2 and 3 are the same function, I only made them to for example purposes.

My confusion lies with "testing3". What I wish to do is access the switch statement by calling the object with a human readable value.  like PlayAgain, or Instructions.

Now as you can see in line 79, this works.. but ONLY if declare the enume in main (or the w/e scope I call the object....

What I would like to do is WITHOUT a 2nd declaration use the enume name.. as in line 82?

Is that possible .. and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scope your enums when using them outside of the class itself.

eg:

```
Func( cEnumtest::PlayAgain );
```

some other tips:

your enums are essentially integer constants.  I suggest you have a naming convention that differentiates them from other code strictly for code-readability and clairty's sake.

eg:  ('k' stands for constant ; 'c' would normally be used to indicate a class data type so that's why 'k' :)

```
enum eGameActions
{
    kActionPlay,
    kActionQuit,
    kActionSaveGame
};
```

Comment: no.. the Class definition scope, not the instance.  
eg:  enumTEST::Instructions

Comment: KenK, I am sorry I do not know what you mean by that? TESTIT.testing3(enumTEST::Instructions); // dosn't work!! 'Instructions' : cannot access private enumerator declared in class 'enumTEST'

Comment: you have a class called enumTEST.  you have an instance of that class called TESTIT;  you access the enum by referencing their owning scope. ie the class (or namespace) where it is declared. and yes.. i forget to notice the fact that you defined them as private. (thx eelerjr12
)